# Printing string variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, io, console

I'm getting some weird output when running (seemingly simple) code. Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a password: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    input.next();
    String s = input.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

And the output I get after compiling successfully is:

```
Enter a password: 
hello
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=5][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]
```

Which is sort of weird. What's happening and how do I print the value of `s`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're getting the `toString()` value returned by the Scanner object itself which is not what you want and not how you use a Scanner object. What you want instead is the data *obtained by* the Scanner object.  For example,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String data = input.nextLine();
System.out.println(data);
```

Please read the tutorial on how to use it as it will explain all.

**Edit**
Please look here: [Scanner tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)

Also have a look at the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) which will explain some of the finer points of Scanner's methods and properties.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestApplication {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      System.out.print("Enter a password: ");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String password = null;
      try {
         password = br.readLine();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("IO error trying to read your password!");
         System.exit(1);
      }
      System.out.println("Successfully read your password.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Why use a BufferedReader instead of Scanner? What's wrong with using a Scanner object?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Indeed. I rephrased my answer to reflect it's just another option.

Answer (score 2):

```
input.next();
String s = input.toString();
```

change it to

```
String s = input.next();
```

May be that's what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is more likely to get you what you want:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = input.next();
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the wrong value. Instead if the string you print the scanners object. Try this

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = input.next();
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have tried all the other answers, and it still hasn't work, you can try skipping a line:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.nextLine();
String s = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("String is " + s);
```